# How do dev files work?

Tags: linux, file, c, udev

How guys from linux make `/dev` files. You can write to them and immediately they're erased. 
I can imagine some program which constantly read some dev file:

```
FILE *fp;
char buffer[255];
int result;
fp = fopen(fileName, "r");
if (!fp) {
    printf("Open file error");
    return;
}
while (1)
{

    result = fscanf(fp, "%254c", buffer);
    printf("%s", buffer);
    memset(buffer, 0, 255);
    fflush(stdout);
    sleep(1);
}
fclose(fp);
```

But how to delete content in there? Closing a file and opening them once again in "w" mode is not the way how they done it, because you can do i.e. `cat > /dev/tty`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What are files? Files are names in a directory structure which denote objects. When you open a file like `/home/joe/foo.txt`, the operating system creates an object in memory representing that file (or finds an existing one, if the file is already open), binds a descriptor to it which is returned and then operations on that file descriptor (like `read` and `write`) are directed, through the object, into file system code which manipulates the file's representation on disk.

Device entries are also names in the directory structure. When you open some `/dev/foo`, the operating system creates an in-memory object representing the device, or finds an existing one (in which case there may be an error if the device does not support multiple opens!). If successful, it binds a new file descriptor to the device obejct and returns that descriptor to your program. The object is configured in such a way that the operations like `read` and `write` on the descriptor are directed to call into the specific device driver for device `foo`, and correspond to doing some kind of I/O with that device.

Such entries in `/dev/` are not files; a better name for them is "device nodes" (a justification for which is the name of the `mknod` command). Only when programmers and sysadmins are speaking very loosely do they call them "device files".

When you do `cat > /dev/tty`, there isn't anything which is "erasing" data "on the other end". Well, not exactly. Basically, `cat` is calling `write` on a descriptor, and this results in a chain of  function calls which ends up somewhere in the kernel's tty subsystem. The data is handed off to a tty driver which will send the data into a serial port, or socket, or into a console device which paints characters on the screen or whatever. Virtual terminals like `xterm` use a pair of devices: a master and slave pseudo-tty. If a tty is connected to a pseudo-tty device, then `cat > /dev/tty` writes go through a kind of "trombone": they bubble up on the master side of the pseudo-tty, where in fact there is a `while (1)` loop in some user-space C program receiving the bytes, like from a pipe. That program is `xterm` (or whatever); it removes the data and draws the characters in its window, scrolls the window, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Unix is designed so that devices (tty, printer, etc) are accessed like everything else (as a file) so the files in /dev are special pseudo files that represent  the device within the file-system.

You don't want to delete the contents of such a device file, and honestly it could be dangerous for your system if you write to them willy-nilly without understanding exactly what you are doing.

Answer (score 2):

Device files are not normal files, if "normal file" refers to an arbitrary sequence of bytes, often stored on a medium.  But not all files are normal files.

More broadly, files are **an abstraction** referring to a system service and/or resource, a service being something you can send information to for some purpose (e.g., for a normal file, write data to storage) and a resource being something you request data from for some purpose (e.g., for a normal file, read data from storage).  C defines a standard for interfacing with such a service/resource.

Device files fit within this definition, but they do not not necessarily match my more specific "normal file" examples of reading and writing to and from storage.  You can directly create dev files, but the only meaningful reason to do so is within the context of a kernel module. More often you may refer to them (e.g., with udev), keeping in mind they are actually created by the kernel and represent an interface with the kernel.  Beyond that, the functioning of the interface differs from dev file to dev file.

Answer (score 1):

I've also found quiet nice explanation:

http://lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch18.pdf